# React Hook Form: Register and handleSubmit are not functions when passing through the props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-typescript

I want to use react-hook-form to validate the inputs. I should pass register and handleSubmit from parent to child components because the inputs based on the selection are different. When register and handleSubmit functions are passed **as props**
React gives me an error saying **TypeError:register and handleSubmit are not functions**

Note!.I switched from the latest version to react-hook-form V6.12.2.Thought that the error is coming from the version but nothing has changed.

**Parent.tsx**

```
export const RequestForm  =()=>{
    const { handleSubmit , register} = useForm()
    const handleRegistration = (data:any) => console.log(data,);
   
    return (
    <div  className="request_form">
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleRegistration)}>
        {(selectedServicesTypes == "Transcriptions - Audio/Video")
            ?
    (<RequestTranscriptions handleRegistration={handleRegistration}
                                       register={register}
                                       handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>)
            :
            (selectedServicesTypes== "Closed Captions - English")
             ?
            (<RequestClosedCaptions/>) 
             : 
            (selectedServicesTypes == "Global Subtitles")  
             ? 
             (<RequestGlobalSubtitles/>)
             : 
             (<NewReq />)
             }
      </form>
    </div>
    )}
```

**Reusable Select.tsx component**

```
export const PrimarySelect:React.FC<SelectProps> =({onChange,className, values, handleRegistration,register,handleSubmit})=>{
  const getSelection = useSelector(transactionReqSelectors.selectService)
   return (
       <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, }}>
         <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Select</InputLabel>
            <Select
                value={getSelection}
                className={className}
                name="Select"
     // When i change ref={register} react is not throwing an error but do not getting values. 
     // When i write ref={register("Select")} i am getting an error.
                ref={register("Select")}
                labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
                id="demo-multiple-name"
                onChange={onChange}
                input={<OutlinedInput label="Select" />}>
                {values?.map((name) => (
                    <MenuItem
                        ref={register}
                        value={name.type}
                    >
                        {name.type}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </form>
        </FormControl>
)}
```

Guys what i did wrong? How to fix an error and get the input fields values.?

Comment: Please make sure to provide a [mcve]. In particular, you miss here `SelectProps` and `RequestTranscriptions`.